# Fade-in pictures on page load with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using this jQuery snippet to produce the effect of picture fading-in one-by-one when the page is loading:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

    animatePictures('img');  

});

function animatePictures(selection) {
    elementsToAnimate = jQuery(selection);
    elementsToAnimate.hide().each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).delay(i * 500).fadeIn(5000);
    });
}
```

This roughly does the trick, but as you can see, the assets are first loaded, then they are hidden when the DOM is ready and then faded-in in 500ms intervals.

I was wondering if you could tell me how I can make it properly so that pictures really fade-in as the site is loading, and are not **first** hidden and **then** faded-in.

I will appreciate all suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: you must first ensure the images have been loaded, so each loaded image will be inserted into the DOM and only then transition it to view. you code will not make sure images are faded-in one after the other..

Comment: look your code works good .. but if you can say an example for what you want to do  cause I not understand do you want hide it first and fadeIn or show it and fadeOut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your css set all your pics to be display:none

```
img{display: none;}
```

Then use:

```
function animatePictures() {
   jQuery('img').each(function(i) {
      jQuery(this).delay(i * 500).fadeIn(5000);
    });
}
jQuery(window).load(function($) { animatePictures(); });
```

by using the window load all your pictures will be loaded in memory and can be shown separately than the rate of download... You might think of using a lazy loader script instead if you are trying to optimize your page...

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple solution is to use just css:

```
img{/*select the selector*/
  display: none;
}
```